# Variable Assignment in Community Builder Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community-builder

When using Community Builder - if you add an sObject Detail page - you're able to set the design parameter as {!recordId} when you add the component to your page like this:

[image]

Are there any such variables for the logged in user that we can also access?  I'm trying to make a dashboard and I need to pass in the ContactId of the logged in user if that's possible.  I can't find anything in the docs about what's available to set in these property fields.

Another option would be to set it directly in the Lightning Component as an attribute - but again, I can't find anywhere that says this is possible.  Something like:

```
<aura:attribute name="userId" type="Id" default="{!LoggedInUserId}"/>
```

Are either of these possible?  Or do I have to fetch the data via apex every time?

Answer (score 2):

This does work but it's not documented so not really a good idea:

```
$A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id")
```

The only documented way I think is to call a server side controller action: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm

You'd probably want to fetch something like the UserId/ContactId once in your doInit.

Comment: right - the painful part is you have to use that in every controller, or you have to pass it in as a param, but either way you need to actively fetch it every time.  Just kind of quirky compared to VF w/Apex controllers.  I suppose the extra layers cause for extra data handling.